# android studio desalinhando formulário de login

Tags: android, android-layout

criei uma tela de login no android estudio, e deixo tudo alinhado no centro da tela do celular, mas quando vou rodar com o avd ou genymotion, ele joga o formulario tudo para o canto, alguem pode me ajudar ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu creio que vc deveria ler isso aqui: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). E isso aqui tb: [Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Sem você postar o código, fica difícil adivinhar qual é o seu problema.

Comment: O amigo Raoni BZ ja me Respondeu !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renam o `RelativeLayout` é um pouco chato mesmo, você precisa criar "âncoras" (referência entre os elementos)(`alinhamento entre os elementos`).

Geralmente a maioria usa o `Linear Layout`, com mais layouts dentro dele mesmo, é bem mais simples !

Existem muitos vídeos que mostram como usar o `Relative`.
Dê uma olhada nesse:
https://www.thiengo.com.br/relativelayout-no-android-entendendo-e-utilizando

Comment: ah sim, agora eu entendo, vc pode me explicar melhor o linear layout, ou me mandar links de videos ou artigos com o exemplo que vc me passou ? muito obrigado desde já !!!

Comment: Esse que passei está legal, vou ver se acho um tutorial com imagens. Porque é tanto material pronto, que não vira fazer outro ! rs

Comment: ahh sim, entendi, de qualquer forma então, muito obrigado, aguardo seu retorno !!!

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/linear-table-e-relative-layouts-com-android-studio/34127

Comment: Basicamente você fará `ligações`, `relacionamentos` entre os `elementos`, com os pontos que cada um tem, na `tela azul`. Geralmente o primeiro elemento você relaciona ele com o topo da tela e a lateral, por ex.. E assim em diante.

Comment: entendi, vou ler um pouco mais e fazer teste, muito obrigado !!!